# Bound function removing itself

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to listen to an element when the transition ends to do some stuff like adding / removing classes.

The problem is now when I use `.bind()` it creates a new function but I want to remove the event listener when the `transitionend` event fires automatically. Is this possible?

My workaround was now that I have an variable outside and assign my function to it and in my `someFunc` I remove it with `this.reference`

```js
let box = document.querySelector("div");

class test {
   constructor() {
      this.reference = null;
   }
   someFunc(box) {
      //do some stuff
      box.removeEventListener("transitionend", this.reference);
   }
   addHandler(box) {
      let func = this.someFunc.bind(this, box);
      this.reference = func;
      box.addEventListener("transitionend", func);
   }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It gets kinda hard to keep the overview in my application as it grows so I want to ask is there an "automatic" way to remove the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on [which browsers you want to suppor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility)t, you can pass the `once` option:

```
let box = document.querySelector("div");

class test {
   constructor() {
      this.reference = null;
   }
   someFunc(box) {
      //do some stuff
   }
   addHandler(box) {
      let func = this.someFunc.bind(this, box);
      box.addEventListener("transitionend", func, {once: true});
   }
}
```

From MDN:

> **once**
> A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

---

You can always write your own helper function to do the same:

```
function once(element, type, handler) {
   function wrapper(event) {
      element.removeEventListener(type, wrapper);
      handler.call(this, event);
   }
   element.addEventListener(type, wrapper);
}

let box = document.querySelector("div");

class test {
   constructor() {
      this.reference = null;
   }
   someFunc(box) {
      //do some stuff
   }
   addHandler(box) {
      let func = this.someFunc.bind(this, box);
      once(box, "transitionend", func);
   }
}
```